# jQuery: How to get value of a particular data attribute from selected datalist (html5) option?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

html:

```
<input list="items" id="item">

<datalist id="items">
  <option value="A item"  data-xyz = "1" >
  <option value="aa item" data-xyz = "2" >
  <option value="C item"  data-xyz = "3" >
  <option value="D item"  data-xyz = "4" >
  <option value="E item"  data-xyz = "5" >
</datalist> 

<input type="button" id="button" value="Get xyz" />
```

js:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
       alert($("#items option:selected").attr('data-xyz'));
});
```

[link to jsbin](http://jsbin.com/emibeh/1/edit)

**Query:**

> I just need to access the value of 'data-xyz' from selected datalist
>    option on click of "#button" or any event.
>
> *jQuery version: 1.7.2*
>
> **Thanks.**

Comment: Why do you use `attr()` instead of `data()`?

Comment: will that make any difference ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`datalist` is simply a storage for autocomplete. Since it could be used for multiple elemnts in page, it wil not have a selected property.

You will need to locate the applicable option yourself such as the following

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    var val = $('#item').val()
    var xyz = $('#items option').filter(function() {
        return this.value == val;
    }).data('xyz');
    /* if value doesn't match an option, xyz will be undefined*/
    var msg = xyz ? 'xyz=' + xyz : 'No Match';
    alert(msg)

})
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/shcRJ/

Comment: Hi. What if  I have more data attributes and want to get them is an array?